# In the temple of the Many Faced God, what could be the purpose of putting heads in columns?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the city of Braavos, Arya was able to go inside the temple of the Many Faced God.  Is there an explanation for keeping heads of dead men in columns or towers inside the temple?

Comment: Is your question about why they're keeping faces in the first place or why on columns? Columns i think is pure imagination from the show's creators. As for the reason why, well because the temple of the many faced god is an assassin's league, they use those faces to perform assassinations as we will see in the series soon I'm sure. You see shifting faces is not as magical as shown in the season one with Jaqen, the operation requires another face ready to be implemented.

Comment: @yondaime008 - In Season 2 of the TV series, Jaqen H'ghar changes his face almost instantly, although it's hard to tell if it's magic or if he has simply removed a face disguise (Jaqen's back is turned to Arya when he performs the trick).

Comment: @RobertF In the books: "Jaqen passed a hand down his face from forehead to chin, and where it went he changed. His cheeks grew fuller, his eyes closer; his nose hooked, a scar appeared on his right cheek where no scar had been before. And when he shook his head, his long straight hair, half red and half white, dissolved away to reveal a cap of tight black curls." (A Clash of Kings - Arya IX) -- Found via http://asearchoficeandfire.com/

Comment: @BCdotWEB - Thanks for posting - the quote implies some level of magic is involved, especially with the hair changing.

Comment: @RobertF Here's an excerpt from A Feast for Crows - Arya II: “That’s not how I meant. Jaqen used magic.” “All sorcery comes at a cost, child. Years of prayer and sacrifice and study are required to work a proper glamor.”

Comment: @RobertF we do not know exactly yet what goes in the process, in A Dance With Dragon we have a short glimpse of the operation, and as far as it is described, little to no magic was involved, but maybe it depends on the level of mastery of the technique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The faces on the walls have been "collected" by the faceless men. These faces can then be used by the faceless men, so a faceless man can appear as any of the faces on the walls.

> They also cure the faces of the dead who come to die in their sanctuary, hanging these on the wall as macabre masks for use in their disguises during assassination contracts. These are more than masks, however, and the wearer assumes the true appearance when applied using a tribute of one's own blood to moisten the application. In this way, the Faceless Men are using tools as part of their disguise, rather than a reliance on glamours or outright magic for disguises, like Melisandre or other followers of R'hllor.

http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Faceless_Men

Comment: This description doesn't seem to be sourced, though. And it seems to contradict Arya's impression of Jaqen's transformation, which comes off as more or less magical.